# ValueError: qk and pk must have same shape - scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon

Tags: python, scipy, topic-modeling

I am calling jensen_shannon(query,matrix) function below to find most similar documents of document query in in matrix of documents

```
def jensen_shannon(query, matrix):
"""
This function implements a Jensen-Shannon similarity
between the input query (an LDA topic distribution for a document)
and the entire corpus of topic distributions.
It returns an array of length M where M is the number of documents in the corpus
"""
# lets keep with the p,q notation above
p = query[None,:].T # take transpose
q = matrix.T # transpose matrix
m = 0.5*(p + q)
return np.sqrt(0.5*(entropy(p,m) + entropy(q,m)))
```

Shape of query : (100,)

Shape of matric: (10804, 100)

Error traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-86cb68dd862d> in <module>
      1 # this is surprisingly fast
----> 2 most_sim_ids = get_most_similar_documents(new_doc_distribution,doc_topic_dist)

<ipython-input-102-c0fb95224e87> in get_most_similar_documents(query, matrix, k)
      6     print(query.shape)
      7     print(matrix.shape)
----> 8     sims = jensen_shannon(query,matrix) # list of jensen shannon distances
      9     return sims.argsort()[:k] # the top k positional index of the smallest Jensen Shannon distances

<ipython-input-74-6ffb0ec54e9a> in jensen_shannon(query, matrix)
     10     q = matrix.T # transpose matrix
     11     m = 0.5*(p + q)
---> 12     return np.sqrt(0.5*(entropy(p,m) + entropy(q,m)))

~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py in entropy(pk, qk, base, axis)
   2668         qk = asarray(qk)
   2669         if qk.shape != pk.shape:
-> 2670             raise ValueError("qk and pk must have same shape.")
   2671         qk = 1.0*qk / np.sum(qk, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
   2672         vec = rel_entr(pk, qk)

ValueError: qk and pk must have same shape.
```

[Add axis parameter for scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11325)  but it doesn't accept axis parameters in the function.

Does anybody have any idea what I am missing? Any lead highly appreciated. Thanks.

FYI: I am trying this kaggle code
https://www.kaggle.com/ktattan/lda-and-document-similarity/data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`p = query[None,:].T + np.zeros([100, 10804])`

100 = number of topics
10804 = number of documents

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself.  scipy version 1.3.0 still behaves as expected by the Jensen-Shannon formula you're using.